# Flutter ColorScheme not applying colors

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme, flutter-material

I'm trying to use a dark theme in a Flutter app but everything seems wrong. I'm using dark theme like this.

```
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.from(
  useMaterial3: true,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
    brightness: Brightness.dark, // tried with or without this line
  ),
  textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(),
);
```

With this *ThemeData* my app's background is dark but the texts are also dark which should not be dark.

Here is what I see in Light Theme.

[image: Light theme screenshot]

Here is what I see in Dark Theme.

[image: dark theme screenshot]

I can't see why the **Categories** text is black.

This is my Text Widget:

```
const Text(
  'Categories',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
),
```

I want it to be in a light color when I don't give any color values to the Text widgets.

I've tried to use ColorScheme with a seed,

I've tried also set all custom colors in ColorScheme like *onPrimary*, *onBackground* -and all the others- but the Text was still a black color.

In the AppBar on the otherhand, it works just right. White text on a black background.

What am I missing?

[image: dark theme appbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass current theme's `textTheme` to GoogleFonts.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: _buildTheme(Brightness.light),
        darkTheme: _buildTheme(Brightness.dark),
        themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
        home: const Home());
  }

  ThemeData _buildTheme(Brightness brightness) {
    var baseTheme = ThemeData(brightness: brightness);

    return baseTheme.copyWith(
      colorScheme: _customColorScheme,
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.lobsterTextTheme(baseTheme.textTheme),
      useMaterial3: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add color inside `GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme()`

like this code

```
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.from(
  useMaterial3: true,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
    brightness: Brightness.dark, // tried with or without this line
  ),
  textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(color: Colors.white), //change it with the color you want
);
```

Comment: You cant set color parameter inside `GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme`.

Comment: That was not 100% true. GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme does not take any color argument. It takes a TextTheme argument so I solved the problem by adding a default text theme inside of robotoTextTheme like this;

textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(
    ThemeData.dark().textTheme,
 ),

Comment: I don't have my IDE now so I just gave you an idea where you can add parameters .